# Replace Wall Receptacle / Outlet - What's the Right Leviton Model

Tags: receptacle

Does anyone know what is the difference between a Leviton 16252-WS outlet versus a 16252-W? The "WS" version sells for 4.99 at Home Depot (http://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Decora-Plus-15-Amp-Duplex-Outlet-White-R62-16252-0WS/100191324?keyword=16252-0ws) while the "W" version sells for 2.91 at an online wholesale store (http://www.westsidewholesale.com/leviton-16252-w.html).

Was wondering if they are the same.

Background context: I'm attempting to replace many of our home's outlets and came into this issue.  I've originally purchased standard Leviton 15A-125v outlets, and it worked perfectly for first of few of the outlets I plan to replace. However, I also encountered many outlets where the wires seem to be too thick to fit into the standard outlets.  I went back to Home Depot and was pointed to "heavy duty" outlets that have a larger wire holes, but the price is more than twice of the standard version. Considering I need to replace ~30 outlets, this would be quite the hit on my wallet. I couldn't find anything about the "WS" version anywhere online, including the official site, but found "W" version which is considerably cheaper.

Edit: I wasn't expecting a reply but still did sent an email to Leviton, and they responded today!  According to the person on email, the two models I've listed above are identical.  He seems to imply the ending characters on the product number are per retailer.

Comment: This is purely opinion i'm providing, but the "stab-in" type fixtures are TERRIBLE and are quite unsafe in the long term. Metal expands and contracts when it changes temperature, over time the wires can and will work themselves out of the stabbed-in ports on the back of the cheap devices. Buy a box of 10 of the heavy duty type and they should cost a bit less.

Comment: Thanks cathode! I had no idea. See my comment below in response to Speedy's answer.  I thought the holes "should have fitted" and were the preferred method. Not surprisingly, I was wrong! (edit: did you mean "tamper resist" when you said "heavy duty"? The heavy duty receptacles actually provides bigger stab holes, and they did not come in boxes of 10.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16252-0WS is a "heavy duty" "Decora Plus" version of the 16252. The "W" simply means white.

If your home is wired with plastic boxes, or even has ground tails to the receptacles already, then the self-grounding devices are not needed/wanted. You'd just be spending more money for no reason. You should however use TR, or tamper resistant, receptacles.

These are what you are looking for: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Decora-15-Amp-Tamper-Resistant-Duplex-Outlet-White-10-Pack-M22-T5325-WMP/100684055

Comment: Thanks!  I did begin the process by purchasing the TR outlets. What confused me were the thick wires that did not "stab-in." I guess in my mind, I thought the "stab-in" method should fit, and when it didn't, it meant I picked the wrong outlet. Time to make returns I guess.  Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, yes. The backstab function while highly unreliable is still code acceptable, but now only for #14. They stopped allowing #12 quite a few years ago.

Comment: Good to know! I'm really glad I asked this question then.

Answer (score 2):

The standard and heavy duty are both 15 amp.  The standard outlet has back wire contact holes for 14 ga.  It is a leaf spring friction edge contact that will fatigue and can work loose over time.  The heavy duty 15 amp outlet is specifically marked back-wire.  The wire insert holes are larger to accept 12 ga.  The contact is a heavier jaw clamp forced down by a screw.

If the standard screw contacts are used, both standard and heavy duty are equivalent.  The heavy duty version just allows 12 ga back-wire installation that is reliable with screw clamp contacts.